# OR clause returning incorrect results SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing a query on a table which contains usernames and user ids. I want to ignore usernames which contain any of the following strings:

LOCKED,
DEACTIVATED,
CLOSED

Taking a record with user id of 1234 and username "myusername LOCKED" as an example

The following query still returns this record

```
select username 
from table where (
instr(username),'LOCKED') = 0
or instr(username),'CLOSED') = 0
or instr(username),'DEACTIVATED') = 0
) and userid = '1234'
```

I would expect no results to be returned as although user id 1234 does exist it does not exist without the string  "LOCKED" in the username.

Why is a record returned?

Is it because the other conditions are true? ie. there is a record with id 1234 and username doesn't contain "CLOSED"? (because it contains "LOCKED"

Comment: FYI . . . Your code is syntactically incorrect because of the parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `or` operator returns `true` if any of the conditions are `true`. That is, even if one of them is `false`, but the other two are `true` the result will be `true`:

**or:**

```
false true true -> true
false false true -> true
```

The `and` operator on the other hand returns `false` if ANY of the conditions are `false`:

**and:**

```
false true true -> false
false false true -> false
```

I think what you want is the `AND` operator instead.
In your head think *"if Y is true AND if X is true___"*. What you had before is *"if Y is true OR if X is true___"*, which of course was returning `true`.

So the solution is:

```
select username 
from table
where (instr(username), 'LOCKED') = 0 and
      instr(username), 'CLOSED') = 0 and
      instr(username), 'DEACTIVATED') = 0
     ) and
    userid = '1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon_Linoff has the correct answer, but I enjoy playing with common table expressions (CTE), so I thought I would add this additional answer in case you wanted to supply the exclusion names as a CSV instead of hard-coding it into the SQL.

```
   WITH
    user_table
    AS
        -- set up some usernames for testing
        (SELECT 'ARBY' AS username
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CLOSED'
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'GOOFY'
           FROM DUAL),
    csv_value
    AS
        (SELECT 'LOCKED, CLOSED, DEACTIVATED' csv
           FROM DUAL),
    exclude_uservalues
    AS
        --  1) Bracket CSV value with commas
        --  2) Remove any spaces (presumes no embedded spaces within CSV values)
        (SELECT ',' || REPLACE (csv, ' ', NULL) || ',' AS csv_values
           FROM csv_value),
    exclude_userset (
                        exclude_user, csv_values
                    )
    AS
        -- This common table expression will split the CSV values into separate records
        -- It works by
        --   a) extracting the value between the first two commas
        --   b) dropping everything before the second comma
        --   c) terminating when there is no second comma
        (SELECT SUBSTR (csv_values, 2, INSTR (csv_values, ',', 2) - 2) AS exclude_user
              , SUBSTR (csv_values, INSTR (csv_values, ',', 2)) AS csv_values
           FROM exclude_uservalues
         UNION ALL
         SELECT SUBSTR (csv_values, 2, INSTR (csv_values, ',', 2) - 2) AS exclude_user
              , SUBSTR (csv_values, INSTR (csv_values, ',', 2)) AS csv_values
           FROM exclude_userset
          WHERE INSTR (csv_values, ',', 2) > 0)
SELECT username
  FROM user_table LEFT OUTER JOIN exclude_userset ON username = exclude_user
 WHERE exclude_user IS NULL;
```

The result of this nonsense is:

```
USERNAME
--------
GOOFY
ARBY
```